# Can not assign ServletContext spring 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, autowired

I am trying to use servletcontext.getRealPath in my Util class to load a file resource (Not part of unit testing) but it does not work.

I tried both to use "implements ServletContextAware":

```
@Component
public class Utils implements ServletContextAware{
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    @Override
    public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        this.servletContext = servletContext;

        System.out.println("**** "+servletContext);
    }
}
```

Which throws NPE since servletcontext is not assigned by spring.

And the @Autowired route:

```
@Component
public class Utils{

    @Autowired
    private ServletContext servletContext;
```

Which throws NoSuchBeanDefinitionException when tomcat is being starting:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.servlet.ServletContext] found for dependency: expected at le
ast 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I am adding the my initialization code in case I am doing something wrong which prevents Spring to inject the right bean.

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebAppInitializer.class);

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) {
        WebApplicationContext rootContext = createRootContext(servletContext);

        configureSpringMvc(servletContext, rootContext);

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic corsFilter = servletContext.addFilter("corsFilter", CORSFilter.class);
        corsFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");

//        configureSpringSecurity(servletContext, rootContext);
    }

    private WebApplicationContext createRootContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

//        rootContext.register(CoreConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class);
        rootContext.register(CoreConfig.class);
        rootContext.refresh();

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
        servletContext.setInitParameter("defaultHtmlEscape", "true");

        return rootContext;
    }
```

CoreConfig.class:

```
@Configuration
public class CoreConfig {

    @Bean
    public CaptionFixture createCaptionFixture() {
        return new CaptionFixture();
    }

    @Bean
    public Utils createUtils () {
        return new Utils();
    }
}
```

Utils is the class with the servlet context.

I have looked at the suggested answers: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739491/servletcontext-and-spring-mvc) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042734/autowired-servletcontext-in-service) and it didnt work.

Comment: You need to declare this bean in a context which has access to a `ServletContext`. You don't seem to be doing that.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - I am not sure I understand what it means or how to do it :).

Can you provide an example or a link?

Comment: Try to call `setServletContext()` on your `rootContext` explicitly. I'm not sure that it gets called when context is passed to constructor of `ContextLoaderListener`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are calling `refresh()` without a `ServletContext` being registered, so none is available when the beans are initialized.

Get rid of this call

```
rootContext.refresh();
```

The `ContextLoaderListener` will take care of calling `refresh()`. The [constructor javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener.html#ContextLoaderListener-org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext-) explains what happens when the `ApplicationContext` passed as an argument isn't refreshed.

Comment: Fixed. Funny I took the configuration from Spring's REST tutorial.   (https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/) - Thanks